# MySql, 2 columns in same table referencing same data

Tags: mysql

My table is formatted as follows where each row represents a paper:

```
ID    TITLE     YEAR    CITE1
1     TITLE1    YEAR1    3
2     TITLE2    YEAR2    1
3     TITLE3    YEAR3    N
...
N     TITLEN     YEARN   2
```

I have selected ID as my primary key. Cite1 contains the ID of a paper which a specific paper cites. So essentially the values in Cite1 are IDs. In the future I want to make connections between a paper and the paper that it cites.

My question is, am I correct to just have ID as my primary key or should I do something to the CITE1 column as it also contains IDs of papers?

I am new to mysql so I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Please post actual queries you are using to select your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you are looking for is a "foreign key".  `ID` is, indeed, the primary key on the table.  `CITE1` is a foreign key that refers to the same table:

```
alter table papers add constraint fk_papers_cite1
    foreign key (cite1) references papers(id);
```

I worry a bit that you have a column called `CITE1` instead of `CITE`.  If papers can cite multiple other papers, then the proper way to represent this is with another table, say `PaperCitations`, which has one row per paper and per paper being cited.  Having multiple columns called things like `CITE1`, `CITE2` and so on is not the way to go.  Storing a delimited list as a string is simply wrong.

Comment: That is what I needed, I wasnt sure if i could have a foreign key referencing a primary key of the same table! thank you

Comment: And sorry I completely understand what you are saying. In fact I do have a separate table for citations in my real database but for now I am working with a very simple database containing just one table and I am working for now that a paper only cites just one other paper so I can begin to make interactions between just two papers instead of multiple. This is my question moving on from this which I would be grateful if you had any advice for! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229693/d3-interactions-between-columns-in-database-table) @GordonLinoff